# How to reference the first is visible view in a listview in the getview method of the listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my specific problem, I have a listview. In this listview I want the first row of the list always has a background color of green. I achieve that using the following code:

```
listView.setSelection(3);
View element = listView.getChildAt(0);
element.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

in the backdrop I am using a custom adapter to populate the listview, as the rows get recycled, the green color is redundant over new rows which appear. Following is my code for the getView method:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View first = listView.getChildAt(0); 

            if (convertView == null){ 
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false); 
            }
            TextView textView = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2));
            textView.setText(lyrics[position]);
            if(){ // Need to reference the first row here. 
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); 
            }else {
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

So in my case I need to know the first visible position in the listview so as I can undo the repetitive background coloring. Is there any way by which I can achieve this? I am open to changing the logic too as long as that is feasible.

Comment: just listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView's views are recycled, so in your adapter `getView` method you should have - probably just before `return convertView`:

```
if(position == 0) {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // or whatever color
}
return convertView;
```

No need for below code that you have:

```
View element = listView.getChildAt(0);
element.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: It happens to me all the time ... as I am a slow writer :D

Comment: Actually this code: View element = listView.getChildAt(0);
element.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); is meant for colouring the first view, as it scrolls up based on time. I had to manuplate the get view method as it was acting erratic coloring all the rows.

Comment: Understood, but if you put the code sample I gave you above, you won't need to call `getChildAt(0)` again.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View first = listView.getChildAt(0); 

        if (convertView == null){ 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false); 
        }
        TextView textView = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2));
        textView.setText(lyrics[position]);
        if(position==getFirstVisiblePosition()){ // Need to reference the first row here. 
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); 
        }else {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```